# How do I print a PCL file in C#?

Tags: c#, printing, printer-control-language

I have a PCL file that I generated using "print to file".

What's the best way to programmatically print this file in C#?

(Given of course that the printer I am printing to supports PCL.)

I know that I can print by invoking from a prompt:

```
copy filename.pcl //location/printername
```

So I would imagine that I could also do the same thing programmatically (using copy)... I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this, say using PrintDocument.

Note that when I use PrintDocument:

```
var pd = new PrintDocument
         {
             DocumentName = @"filename.pcl";
             PrinterSettings = {PrinterName = @"\\location\printername"}
         };

pd.Print();
```

I always get a blank page printed.

Comment: DocumentName is the display name of the print job.  No relation to the file name on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article applies to Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298141), but it is easy enough to follow to be able to apply it to C#, I think. Otherwise, I'll gladly assist you with any problematic parts.

If the printer is on the network, [here's a little funny example of how to talk directly to it](http://odetocode.com/Humor/68.aspx). Not sure if it also works if you simply send the bytes of the PCL to the printer though.

Comment: Haha, +1 for the funny example, Ill have to try it out at work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to have come so late to this question, but I have some code that will do the job.  It was not written by me originally.  I received the code from another programmer's help site, but I can't remember which one.  It works beautifully.  Here is the project, which creates a dll.  To do it yourself, select Create:/Project/Class Library (select Visual C# under project types).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace PrintRaw
{
   public class RawFilePrint
   {
      // Structure and API declarions:
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
      public class DOCINFOA
      {
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
         public string pDocName;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
         public string pOutputFile;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
         public string pDataType;
      }
      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

      // SendBytesToPrinter()
      // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
      // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
      // Returns true on success, false on failure.
      public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
      {
         Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
         IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
         DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
         bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

         di.pDocName = "RAW Document";
         di.pDataType = "RAW";

         if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
         {
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
               if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
               {
                  bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                  EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
               }
               EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
         }
         if (!bSuccess)
         {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
         }
         return bSuccess;
      }

      public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
      {
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
         BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
         Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
         bool bSuccess = false;
         IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
         int nLength;

         nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
         bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
         pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
         Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
         bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
         Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
         return bSuccess;
      }

      public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
      {
         IntPtr pBytes;
         Int32 dwCount;
         dwCount = szString.Length;
         // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
         // the string to ANSI text.
         pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
         SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
         Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Now, to use this code, add the resulting dll as a reference to your project, then call the functions as you need them.  Here is some code where I used it, just today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PclFontTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string szPrinterName = @"\\printserver\LaserJet 2420";

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Fonts\US20HP.FNT");
            string line = (char)27 + "*c32545D";
            line += sr.ReadToEnd();
            line += (char)27 + "*c5F";

            PrintRaw.RawFilePrint.SendStringToPrinter(szPrinterName, line);


        }
    }
}
```

This program reads a PCL Font from a file.  It wraps the font with code to assign a font id of 32545 to it, then calls the dll function SendStringToPrinter.

Comment: I tried to send a full pcl document to a laserjet 4 driver that was set up to print to file, The status on the file just says "Error - Printing"

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are trying to print to a file.  The code above requires a file that contains only PCL code, and you want to send it directly to a printer without windows interfering.  In other words, you seem to be attempting to print to file a file that was already printed to a file.

Comment: Great code @James Carr. Question for you. When sending a file, is there anyway to format it? e.g line spacing, margins, page breaks etc

Answer (score 2):

We use the following methods per DLL Import:

```
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] RawPrinter di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);
```